# Разделители между аргументами в argv при вводе

Tags: bash, macos, argv

*Вопросы:*

1. Как правильно разделять строчные аргументы для argv при вводе их с командной строки?
2. Как вводить многословные аргументы?
3. Какую роль при вводе аргументов играет восклицательный знак?
4. Где можно прочитать о синтаксисе ввода аргументов для argv?

*Система:*

```
macOS: High Sierra v 10.13.3  
Bash: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)  
Terminal: iTerm2 Build 3.1.5  
Compiler: gcc Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

*Есть программа*, которая должна принимать аргументы из командной строки через `argv`. Программа проверяет количество аргументов. Если оно неравно 2, выводит пустую строку. Далее программа ищет первое слово в аргументе 01, пропуская `space` и `tab`. Если слово найдено, выводит его, отрезая всё что следует за ним (`space`, `tab`, `\n`).

Если не использовать при вводе параметров двойные кавычки, то фраза `Hello world` принимается как два аргумента. `Space` работает разделителем. Чтобы проверить работу программы мне надо задать аргумент, состоящий из нескольких слов. Для этого используется двойные кавычки: `"Hello world"`. Программа работает корректно и выводит первое слово `Hello`.

*Проблема* в том, что если внутри аргумента взятого в кавычки присутствует восклицательный знак (`!`). Система воспринимает его как конец аргумента. При запуске с параметром `"Hello world!"` программа выдает

```
dbquote:
```

и ждёт когда я закрою вторые кавычки. После ввода второй кавычки программа завершает работу. Система воспринимает "`!`" как знак синтаксиса, а не как элемент аргумента.

P.S. Проверил в качестве разделителей пробелы, апострофы (' ') и двойные кавычки (" "). Все они разделяют аргументы. В случае применения в качестве разделителей пробелов и двойных кавычек восклицательный знак в аргументе надо экранировать `\!`. В случае использования апострофов экранировать восклицательный знак не надо.

P.P.S. Исправил метки

Comment: Прочтите [25.1 Program Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments), потом сами будете учить разбору `argv[]`

Comment: интерпретация командной строки и разбиение оной на отдельные аргументы зависит только от оболочки и ОС и ни как не связана с языком...

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, где всё это происходит, чтобы не пришлось гадать :)

Comment: Добавил сведения о системе.

Comment: @Ashavan,  `Система воспринимает "!" как знак синтаксиса` -- не могу проверить в МакОС, попробуйте заключать аргументы в апострофы (одиночные кавычки). Наверное, тестировать проще всего командой `/bin/echo`

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я уже сделал это. Метод тыка, безусловно, универсальный инструмент исследования. Моя цель найти сжатую информацию о синтаксисе аргументов argv, желательно на русском. Я не знаю как тестировать с помощью echo.

Comment: @Ashavan, ссылку на описание на английском я вам привел (в первом же комментарии). Там описаны стандартные правила для POSIX систем (и расширения для GNU). Возможно вам следует модифицировать вопрос, сделав акцент на MacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как правильно разделять строчные аргументы для argv при вводе их с командной строки?

Пробелами или пробельными символами.

> Как вводить многословные аргументы?

Для ввода аргументов, содержащих специальные символы существует такая вещь как *квотирование* (*quoting*). Этот механизм описан в соответствующей секции [`man bash`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1&russian=2#lbAR) ; если кратко, то есть три вида квотирования:

- Обратные слеши  (`\`); квотируют один следующий за ними символ:

  ```
  ./program Hello\ world\!
  ```
- Двойные кавычки (`""`); квотируют все символы кроме нескольких специальных: (`` $`\! ``)

  ```
  ./program "Hello world\!"
  ```
- Одинарные кавычки (`''`); квотируют все символы

  ```
  ./program 'Hello world!'
  ```

> Какую роль при вводе аргументов играет восклицательный знак?

В bash это *подстановка из истории* (*history expansion*). Применяется довольно редко т.к. мало-кто помнят её синтаксис и обычно проще отредактировать команду вручную.

В качестве полезной конструкции можно вспомнить `!$` — расширяется в последний аргумент предыдущей команды. Пример использования:

```
ls -l /some/long/path/to/a/file
cat !$ # заменяетя
```

За подробностями см. соотв. [секцию](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1&russian=2#lbCV) `man bash`.

> Где можно прочитать о синтаксисе ввода аргументов для argv?

Первоисточником является документация оболочки, в данном случае уже упомянутый `man bash` и [`info bash`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html). Что-то менее основательное посоветовать сложно — это довольно простая и интуитивно-понятная вещь...